# I want to write a pine code strategy but everytime I get a malfunction that says 'could not find indicator 'sma'

Tags: charts, pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading

i want to create a strategy with pine code that gives me a buy signal everytime when the price of the stock is above the SMA200 and the MACD is below 0 and when the MACD level line crosses the MACD signal line up. Furthermore I want it to give me a short signal everytime the price of the stock is below the SMA200 and when the MACD is above 0 and when the MACD level line crosses the MACD signal line down.

Here is my code

```
//@version=5
strategy("MACD Strategy", overlay=true)

// EMA200
ema200 = sma(close, 200)

// MACD
macdLine = sma(close, 12) - sma(close, 26)
macdSignal = sma(macdLine, 9)

// MACD Level crosses MACD Signal Line up
macdCrossUp = crossover(macdLine, macdSignal)

// MACD Level crosses MACD Signal Line down
macdCrossDown = crossunder(macdLine, macdSignal)
// MACD is above 0
macdAboveZero = macdLine > 0

// MACD is below 0
macdBelowZero = macdLine < 0

// Buy signal
buySignal = close > ema200 and macdCrossUp and macdBelowZero

// Short signal
shortSignal = close < ema200 and macdCrossDown and macdAboveZero

// Plot signals
plot(macdCrossUp ? 1 : na, "MACD Cross Up", color=color.green)
plot(macdCrossDown ? 1 : na, "MACD Cross Down", color=color.red)

// Buy and Short strategy
if (buySignal)
strategy.entry("Buy", buySignal, when = buy)
```

I expected it to show me Buy and Short signals on my TradingView chart. Unfortunately this did not happen as it can not find the indicator called 'sma'.

But it does not work and says everytime that it could not find the function 'sma'

I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me. :)

And sorry for my bad english.

If you need further information, just tell me.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Functions have been moved to dedicated namespaces in `v5`.

So for functions like, `sma`, `crossover`, you should use the `ta` namespace.

```
macdSignal = ta.sma(macdLine, 9)
macdCrossUp = ta.crossover(macdLine, macdSignal)
```

Of course you need to fix that in other places too.

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem! But I got another one. Could you write a pine code where I buy a long position when the conditions are to go long are fullfilled and where I buy a short position when the conditions to go short are fullfilled?